# Cartesian coordinates in Java

Tags: java, graphics, draw

I'm trying to draw a function's curve, so I need a method to convert my curve points coordinates to screen coordinates but I can't get it to work.
Here's the method I use to convert:

```
public Point tradPoint(Point P){     
  Point Ptd = new Point();

  Ptd.x=getWidth()/2 + P.x*getWidth()/20;
  Ptd.y=getHeight()/2 - P.y*getHeight()/20;

  return Ptd;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

I should mention that I'm using a Cartesian coordinate system and a unit=20.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: When you say that a "unit=20" do you mean that one unit in `P` co-ordinates is equal to one twentieth of your width/height? That appears to be what you have coded.

Comment: Please rephrase "doesn't work" .  You are the only one who can see what happens and what you expected to happen.

Comment: it returns Ptd.y always  a negative number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be

```
Ptd.x = getWidth() / 2 + P.x * 20;
Ptd.y = getHeight() / 2 - P.y * 20;
```

where 20 is the unit width.

Also, `Ptd` should be `pTd` or even better `pointTranslated` and `P` should be `p` or `point`.  Java identifiers should start with a lowercase letter and be descriptive.

Comment: thanks a lot,but that didnt work  maybe the unit width im taking is wrong , is there another way ?

Comment: @Mona: This should work.  Maybe there's another problem?  What results are you getting for what inputs?